# Google Chrom не пускает на сайт с не подписанным сертификатом

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Для разработки использую подмененный через hosts файл, google-analytics.com 
Но при попытке зайти на него браузер ругается, что сертификат не подписан. И не предлагает кнопки типа "Перейти всё равно". Раньше кажется такая кнопка была. Не знаю как быть, где выключить это оповещение и позволить мне все-таки, на свой страх и риск, как говорится, попасть на сайт.

Видимо в новой версии Хрома эту кнопку убрали, но я после длительного гугления в интернете, так и не нашёл решения.

Подскажите как попасть на сайт) Safari например пускает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так и не понял смысла этого действия

Answer (score 3):

Это действует **HSTS** ([HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSTS)). Он **обязывает** производить доступ к сайту через проверенное безопасное соединение, не доверяя решения пользователю.

[Конкретно `google-analytics.com`, к тому же, находится в *HSTS preload list* Хрома](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json&l=320), своеобразном "белом списке" доменов, для которых HSTS действует по инициативе **браузера**, а не сервера.

Имея контроль над собственной системой, можно сгенерировать самоподписанный **Certificate Authority** (CA), установить его в систему<sup>[1]</sup>, а затем на его основе сгенерировать собственный сертификат для нужного вам домена (указав его в Common Name при генерации) и выдать его вебсерверу. Тогда браузер, обращающийся за валидацией в системное хранилище сертификатов, будет считать соединение с этим сервером на этот домен доверенным.

Но держите в безопасности сгенерированные ключи, потому что ваша система им безусловно доверяет. Если до них доберётся злоумышленник, то он сможет заставить вашу систему поверить почти во что угодно.

---

- <sup>[1]</sup> Или используйте **Firefox**, который использует собственную пачку сертификатов, не системную. В этом случае CA достаточно установить только в Firefox и вся остальная система сертификатам этого CA верить не будет. Так, наверное, спокойнее.
  [Chrome всегда использует системное хранилище](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy). Его не отучить.